# how to create window without border and with shadow like github app?

Tags: winapi

how to create window which does't have border but it  has behaves like with border . like git-hub app window, it has shadow effect also.how to create window like this.
thank you. using  win 32 c++.

i had tried by handling wm_Ncpaint call but no use.

```
        #include "stdafx.h"
        #include "CustomWindow.h"

        LONG_PTR g_lpCustomWindowptr = NULL;
        BOOL g_bStateofWindow = TRUE;

        // creating window 
        CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES,
                       szWindowClass,
                       szTitle,
                       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                       CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL,
                       NULL, hInstance, NULL);

        void CustomWindow::CreateCustomWindow(HWND hwnd)
        {
            // To set border and handling Doc with default cases
            LONG_PTR lpStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

            lpStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_ACTIVECAPTION );

            //lpStyle |= WS_THICKFRAME;

            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lpStyle);

            //set the customized proc.
            g_lpCustomWindowptr = SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,
                GWLP_WNDPROC,
                (LONG_PTR)CustonWindow_WndProc);
        }

        LRESULT CALLBACK CustomWindow::CustonWindow_WndProc(IN HWND hwnd, 
                                                            IN UINT message, 
                                                            IN WPARAM wParam, 
                                                            IN LPARAM lParam)
        {
            switch (message)
            {
            case WM_SIZE:   
                {           
                    if (SIZE_MAXIMIZED == wParam)
                    {           
                        HMONITOR hmon= MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, 
                            MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

                        MONITORINFO moninfo = {0};

                        moninfo.cbSize= sizeof(moninfo);

                        GetMonitorInfo(hmon, &moninfo);

                        SetWindowPos(hwnd,
                            HWND_TOP, 
                            moninfo.rcWork.left,            
                            moninfo.rcWork.top,
                            moninfo.rcWork.right,
                            moninfo.rcWork.bottom, 
                            SWP_FRAMECHANGED | 
                            SWP_NOREDRAW);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case WM_NCACTIVATE :
                {
                    if (TRUE == wParam)
                    {

                        SendMessage(hwnd,WM_NCPAINT,wParam,0);

                    }
                    else if(FALSE == wParam )
                    {
                        SendMessage(hwnd,WM_NCPAINT,wParam,0);

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
                {   
                    return 0;
                }
                break;

            case  WM_NCPAINT:
                {
                    HDC hDC;

                    hDC = GetWindowDC(hwnd);

                    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(0,0,255));; 

                    SelectObject(hDC, hPen);

                    RECT rcClientRect = {0};

                    GetClientRect(hwnd,&rcClientRect);

                    if(FALSE == wParam)
                    {
                        MoveToEx(hDC,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.top,NULL);

                        LineTo(hDC,rcClientRect.right - 1,rcClientRect.top );

                        LineTo(hDC,rcClientRect.right - 1,rcClientRect.bottom - 1 );

                        LineTo(hDC,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.bottom - 1);

                        LineTo(hDC,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.top);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HPEN hPen1 = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, RGB(255,0,0));; 

                        SelectObject(hDC, hPen1);

                        MoveToEx(hDC,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.top,NULL);

                        LineTo(hDC,rcClientRect.right - 1,rcClientRect.top );

                        LineTo(hDC,rcClientRect.right - 1,rcClientRect.bottom - 1 );

                        LineTo(hDC,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.bottom - 1);

                        LineTo(hDC,rcClientRect.left,rcClientRect.top);
                    }
                    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
                }               


            }
            break;




        }
        return  CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)g_lpCustomWindowptr,
                               hwnd, 
                               message, 
                               wParam, 
                               lParam);
        }
```

Comment: You get the shadow by setting the `CS_DROPSHADOW` style when registering your window class.

Comment: if border is there , shadow will come but iam crating window without border.

Comment: `CS_DROPSHADOW` will add another shadow, not aero. Aero shadow differs for active and inactive window

Answer (score 4):

To create window without border, system menu and titlebar but with Aero shadow you need to do the following:

1. Create window with `WS_CAPTION` style
2. Call `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` WDM API passing 1 pixel top margin
3. Handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message, do not forward call to `DefWindowProc` while processing this message, but just return `0`

Here is a simple example that creates such window using clean Windows API written in Delphi:

```js
program BorderlessWindow;

uses
  DwmApi,
  Winapi.UxTheme,
  Windows, SysUtils, Messages;

{$R *.res}

var
  Msg        : TMSG;
  LWndClass  : TWndClass;
  hMainHandle: HWND;
  lMargins: TMargins;

procedure ReleaseResources;
begin
  PostQuitMessage(0);
end;

function WindowProc(hWnd,Msg:Longint; wParam : WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM):Longint; stdcall;
begin
  case Msg of
      WM_DESTROY: ReleaseResources;
      WM_NCHITTEST: Exit(HTCAPTION);  // This is needed only to move window with mouse
      WM_NCCALCSIZE: Exit(0); // This line will hide default window border and caption
  end;
  Result:=DefWindowProc(hWnd,Msg,wParam,lParam);
end;

begin
  //create the window
  LWndClass.hInstance := hInstance;
  with LWndClass do
    begin
      lpszClassName := 'MyWinApiWnd';
      Style         := 0;//CS_PARENTDC or CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT;
      hIcon         := LoadIcon(hInstance,'MAINICON');
      lpfnWndProc   := @WindowProc;
      hbrBackground := COLOR_BTNFACE+1;
      hCursor       := LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);
    end;

  RegisterClass(LWndClass);
  hMainHandle := CreateWindow(LWndClass.lpszClassName,nil,
        WS_CAPTION or WS_VISIBLE,
        (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) div 2)-190,
        (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) div 2)-170, 386,200,0,0,hInstance,nil);

  if DwmCompositionEnabled then
  begin
    // This API call adds aero shadow
    lMargins.cyTopHeight := 1;
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hMainHandle, lMargins);
  end;

  //message loop
  while GetMessage(Msg,0,0,0) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;
end.
```