# Borderless window. How to add a shadow and remove 1px border?

Tags: windows, winapi, borderless

I need to create a borderless window with specified background color. I know how to remove a non client area and get something like this:

[image]

It's cool but not truly what I want. If you take a closer look at any aero window - there's a shadow around it (actually this is not a shadow but some glow). I found somewhere that I can use this code to add a shadow:

```
const MARGINS shadow_on = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &shadow_on);
```

It's almost do it's job (thought this is absolutely not clear to me - 
documentation says nothing about relationship of shadow and this function). Almost. There's a thin border appeared around the window. It looks like it's semitransparent and it breaks the look and feel of the window:

[image]

I know that it's possible - the visual studio even change the color of this border somehow!

Update: as IInspectable noticed in comments I can use negative margins in `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()`. I set -1 value and got this result:

[image]

As you can see - it's even weirder. I tried to fill a background with color, but without luck.

Comment: You can clip the window area to remove the  glow. Did You try to clip it already in order to remove the glow ? It might be, that You cannot get rid of the glow and use shadow at the same time.

Comment: @icbytes no, you didn't understand - I need a glow - I don't need a border which appears when I'm adding a glow.

Comment: Then do not use the mentioned function. Draw it Yourself. One px lines, on all sides, with a slight ligther green.

Comment: If I'll not use this function there will be no glow at all - like in first screenshot.

Comment: [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512.aspx): *"Use negative margin values to create the "sheet of glass" effect where the **client area is rendered as a solid surface with no window border**."*

Comment: Why not use `CS_DROPSHADOW` in class style?

Comment: @IInspectable Unfortunately this didn't help - I updated a post with a new picture.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani This style gives a shadow on right side and bottom only - not aero shadow.

Comment: I see, calling `DwmExtenFrameIntoClientArea` with negative margin values turns the entire client area into Aero Glass. Have you tried using a margin with all members set to zero?

Comment: Yes - that way there's no shadow (see first screenshot).

Comment: Wait I'm confused. What kind of shadow do you want? Could you produce a mockup of what you want to see? Is `CS_DROPSHADOW` not it?

Comment: @andlabs What I wanted to achieve is called aero shadow - it's a glowing around window perimeter. `CS_DROPSHADOW` adds shadow near bottom and right window edges only. Anyway, I found how to achieve what I want:   1. `CreateWindowEx` with `WS_EX_LAYERED` flag.   2. call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);` - the color should differ from window's background (specified in `WNDCLASSEX`).   3. call `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` with margins where at least one margin not zero.

Comment: All right then. Glad to see you've found how to do it; good luck from here on out!

Comment: @nikitablack:  Could you add an answer to this question, showing a bit more detail like the window and class styles you're using.  I'm unable to get the Aero shadow to appear on a WS_POPUP using the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea as you've shown (with or without the semi-transparent border).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Unfortunately, I don't have a working example and I absolutely don't remember what I did. The only thing I remember is that visual studio (and other MS tools) used another windows for the shadow - that's how they managed to change it's color. Basically they add a new window on every edge and somehow rendered semitransparent glow.

Answer (score 3):

To remove one pixel border after calling this function:

```
const MARGINS shadow_on = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &shadow_on);
```

You need to override WndProc `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message, and return `0` as the result.
Also you need to create window using `WS_CAPTION` style. (On Windows XP this code won't produce rectangular window, but there is no shadow on WinXP, so on Windows XP you should fallback to `WS_POPUP` window style)
By the way, to add shadow it is enough to use this margins:
 
`const MARGINS shadow_on = { 1, 0, 0, 0 };`

Here is clean windows API code example how to create such window, it is written on Delphi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489430/877099